# Self signed certificated - java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation

Tags: android, ssl, openssl, nativescript

I create my own CA authority for local deploy. And APIRest, web and app. So my certificates work well in web.

In android I been configure my `network_security_config.xml` like this way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config>
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="@raw/myca"/>
            <certificates src="system"/>
            <certificates src="user"/>
        </trust-anchors>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

When I run `tns run android` and I try to connect to my api the console show me this error:

> "error": { JS:     "originalStack": "Error: java.net.SocketException:
>   java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing
>   implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: AndroidOpenSSL, class:
>   com.android.org.conscrypt.DefaultSSLContextImpl)\n    at new
>   ZoneAwareError
>   (file:///data/data/org.nativescript.ngsample/files/app/vendor.js:91593:33)\n
>   at onRequestComplete
>   (file:///data/data/org.nativescript.ngsample/files/app/vendor.js:97990:34)\n
>   at Object.onComplete
>   (file:///node_modules/@nativescript/core/http/http-request/http-request.js:43:0)"

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

This was easy. My mistake was not read the documentation. I only need to change mi `security_network_config.xml`

```
        <domain-config>
            <domain includeSubdomains="true">192.168.1.67</domain>
            <trust-anchors>
                <certificates src="@raw/myca"/>
            </trust-anchors>
        </domain-config>
```

Comment: Do we need the `includeSubdomains` for this situation?

Comment: In this case, yes.

Comment: How do we know what subdomain IP address is?